# how would getc(null) generate a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, posix

I am reading *Cyclone: A Safe Dialect of C* by Jim Trevor et. all for a programming languages class. The authors say that if you call `getc(null)` it could cause a segmentation fault--because the C standard does not specify how to handle this operation. I am new to C and don't understand why this would be the case. Is the idea that getc *might* return a pointer to a bad memory address (because the behavior of `getc(null)` is unpredictable)? To me, it does not seem like a security risk because C would be expecting a character literal (not a pointer to a character) from [getC](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/getc/).

Is the worry that the character returned from getc might contain a valid pointer value that could then be assigned to a pointer and used to access an unsafe region of memory? **Or** is the worry that the getc would cause the segmentation fault (and not the calling function).

Comment: Passing NULL pointers to things not expecting NULL pointers generally causes them segfault. I don't know why you would think it has anything to do with the return value.

Comment: getc() returns a character and the return value has nothing to do with pointers.  Read the man page.

Comment: @JimBalter I'm just new to C. Your comment is basically the answer.

Comment: I understand that you're new to C ... you said so. What I don't understand is why, when your source says that a *call* to `getc(NULL)` can cause a segfault, you expect the fault to happen *after* the call. I also don't understand why you talk about characters containing pointer values. Being new to a language does not necessarily imply or justify being conceptually muddled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't read the GNU C library source code (but I have read 'info getc'), but you are supposed to pass a pointer to getc. If the pointer you pass is a null pointer, getc *might* try to read/write to it as though it were a valid pointer, which would generate a segfault.

Comment: The pointer provided to getc() is a FILE * pointer to an open stream that was opened with fopen().  So getc() does not try to read/write to the pointer.  It instead uses the pointer to the FILE object in order to know the stream to read from in order to obtain the next character from the stream.  The segmentation violation would come from the FILE pointer containing an invalid address whether NULL or an address out of the address space or the address to something that is not a FILE object.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/getc/